# Does the STL contain a hashtable?

Tags: c++, stl, hashtable

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Hashtable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133569/hashtable-in-c)
>   [can anybody offer a simple hash_map example in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179946/can-anybody-offer-a-simple-hash-map-example-in-c)

Does the STL contain an implementation of a hashtable?

If so, can you provide a brief example of how to use it?

Comment: there is, and I think it's called hashmap or hash_map. Google should be able to help you out.

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133569/hashtable-in-c. This is actually the first entry in the "Related" list on the RHS of this page. And for a use case, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179946/can-anybody-offer-a-simple-hash-map-example-in-c

Comment: also duplicate of first related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133569/hashtable-in-c

Answer (score 13):

Current standard implementation doesn't, [STL::TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1) does, see [Unordered Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_map_(C%2B%2B)).

Most modern compilers have a TR1 implementation, if that fails, you may always use the [Boost TR1](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_tr1.html) implementation.

- MSVC has it for VS2008 via service pack 1
- GCC has it shipped with 4.x, but you can make it work with 3.4.x too AFAIR

Usage is almost the same as with a std::map.

Comment: std::unordered_map is now part of the STL for c++ 11 - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Answer (score 3):

> **While not officially part of the STL standard,** hash_map and hash_set are commonly used to improve searching times......

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d462wfh%28VS.80%29.aspx

So, long story short--no .

Comment: std::unordered_map is now part of the STL for c++ 11 - en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Answer (score 0):

A quick google came up with [this description of hash_map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html).

Comment: I guess this was down voted because hash_map is not standard.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but in future please provide  a sentence or two explaining what "this" links to.

Comment: This link is dead.  Please don't post links as answers for this exact reason.