# What kind of hashing function does STL set use?

Tags: c++, stl, set

STL **set** are the C++ version of hashtables. What kind of hashing function does STL **set** use to map its keys to values , i cant seem to find any reference to it , most websites explain [how to use](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) the function but hardly talk about the hashing function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the STL contain a hashtable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192976/does-the-stl-contain-a-hashtable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STL sets are not hashtables at all. They are ordered containers. You have to explicitly use the unordered containers to get hashing behavior. Some STL implementations use RB-trees, but you'll need to read the source of the one you are using.

Comment: what is the equivalent of hashtables in C++ then ??

Comment: @Computernerd `std::unordered_set`. You will need C++11, otherwise there is `boost::unordered_set` or `std::tr1::unordered_set` (accessing this through Boost.TR1 is probably the best, most portable way).