# Ways store some numbers (see inside for detail on this) in C++

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, data-structures, unordered-map

I need to store some numbers like this

```
key => (four integers, between 0 to 30 (maxmimum), -1 means NULL)
125 => (1,3,5,20)
80 => (4,2,-1,-1)
20 => (10,12,21,3)
...
```

I need the fastest random access. Actually it is going to be a table of data for my application. I thought of storing these values inside a header and call them where ever I need. I mostly do scripting (PHP/Python) and there I have Arrays/Dictionaries. But what about C++?

I have found map and unordered_map (which seems the former is better for random access) so far.

Comment: `unordered_map` provides amoritized constant time on reads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`std::unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) to hold this, ie: `std::unordered_map<int, std::array<int, 4>>`.

The use of `unordered_map` will provide faster access by key.  From [this documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/):

> unordered_map containers are faster than map containers to access individual elements by their key, although they are generally less efficient for range iteration through a subset of their elements.

Comment: Yes, that documentation was the first when I googles, but I was wondering if there is another way I am missing. I will accept this answer and use it sometime later, if no one has another suggestion. BTW, can anyone give me a code example for unordered_map? I read somewhere that it need hashing function and I have to build it.

Comment: @thelastblack If you're using an int as a key, you won't need a custom hashing function.  Usage is pretty simple - see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2179985/65358  for an example

Comment: Great! I'm going for it. ThanQ!