# hash table with 2 items as a key?

Tags: c++, hash

There is a [great example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179946/i-would-like-to-see-a-hash-map-example-in-c) of a simple hash table in `C++` for a single key, but I would like to hash on a `<int, double>` combination so that, for example `h[5, 0.1]` will return a `double`. Is this possible?

One possible method to get around this is to create an array of `unordered_map`s, and then have the `key` be a double. So, for example, I could simply call `h[5][0.1]` and get the `double` value back. In this the best way to go about this or can I create a multi-variabled key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Make your key `std::pair<int, double>` (or tuple of `<int, double>`). Define appropriate hashing function (I would say hash(int) ^ hash(double) might work)

Comment: So I would still need to define a `R X R -> R` function for the hash function to compute the value? I am trying to use this hash map to avoid computation. If I have computed f(a,b), then store the value and just hash for it later, but if I need to compute f(a,b) to use as the key, this defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Laurbert515 -  The `unordered_map` in you example uses `std::hash<T>` internally. If you have both `int` and `double` in your key, you will have to provide a hasher that combines `std::hash<int>` and `std::hash<double>`. That's it.

Comment: @Laurbert515 As myself and Bo proposed, you have hash implementation for int and double already. So just write one liner which combines them, I proposed using ^, there are other alternatives like http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/hash_combine_id241013.html